# Nonhomogeneous linear system that has constant coefficients

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How can I start to find the general solution of the following nonhomogeneous system

$$
\dot{x} = \left[ \begin{array}{ c c } 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{array} \right]x + 
\left[ \begin{array}{ c } \cos(t)  \\ \cosh(t) \end{array} \right]
$$

---

Things I already know:

for eigenvalue $r = λ + µi$ and corresponding eigenvector $w = a + bi$, the general solution of the homogeneous system is given by

$$
xh = c_1e^{λt}[a\cos(µt) − b\sin(µt)] + c_2e^{λt}[a\sin(µt) + b\cos(µt)]
$$

The first step is something like this?
$$
x_p = a\cos(t) + b\sin(t) + c\cosh(t) + d\sinh(t)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write $$A = \pmatrix{1&1\\-1&1} = \sqrt 2\pmatrix{\cos (\pi/4)&\sin(\pi/4)\\-\sin(\pi/4)&\cos(\pi/4)}$$ the transformation $A$ is a clockwise rotation by $\pi/4$ followed by a dilatation of $\sqrt 2.$  therefore $$e^{At} = e^{\sqrt 2 t} \pmatrix{\cos (\pi t/4)&\sin(\pi t/4)\\-\sin(\pi t/4)&\cos(\pi t/4)} $$  you can use the variation of parameters to write a particular a solution in the form $$\int_0^te^{A(t-s)}\pmatrix{\cos s\\\cosh s}ds $$ or you can try an ansatz like you suggested in the question.

---

p.s. the de in component form is $$\begin{align}\dot x &= x + y + \cos t\\\dot y &= -x + y+\cosh t \end{align}$$  differentiating wrt $t,$ we have 
$$\begin{align}\ddot x &= \dot x + \dot y - \sin t = 2y+\cos t + \cosh t- \sin t \\
&=2(\dot x - x-\cos t)+\cos t + \cosh t- \sin t \\
\ddot x-2\dot x + 2x &= \cosh t -\cos t - \sin t\end{align}$$

you can sub $x = a\cos t + b \sin t + c \cosh t+ d \sinh t$ into the last equation and determine the constants $a, b, c, d.$ once you have them use $y = \dot x - y-\cos t$ to find $y.$

Comment: How would I go about writing it in the form $$x_p(t) =a\cos(t) + b\sin(t) + c\cosh(t) + d\sinh(t)$$

Comment: Could you show me how to go about with ansatz?

Comment: you will need another similar expression for the second component $y$. then you sub both  in $\dot x = Ax + f$ and set the coefficients of $\sin, \cos, \cdots$  equal on both sides. if that is too much get a second order equation for $x$ and sub the expression you have.

Comment: ok I will try that, but could you alos explain the steps in the method you showed a bit more :) Especially the part "variation of perameters"  I don't understand how to write them in this  form $$\int_0^te^{A(t-s)}\pmatrix{\cos s\\\cosh s}ds $$